# (java)deadlock when calling shell command with Runtime

Tags: java, runtime, deadlock

I use the following code to read the log file. After running for a period of time, I can't call the shell command.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    resultBuilder.append(line).append("\r\n");
}
```

Then I use jstack to read the log.

```
"clusteredScheduler_Worker-3" #21 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104d3e2800 nid=0x101c5 in Object.wait() [0x00007f0fd8415000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
    - locked <0x00000003d55467e0> (a java.lang.Object)

"clusteredScheduler_Worker-2" #20 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104d3e0800 nid=0x101c4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f0fd8516000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
    - locked <0x00000003d5546550> (a java.lang.Object)

"clusteredScheduler_Worker-1" #19 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104d3df000 nid=0x101c3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f0fd8617000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
    - locked <0x00000003d55462c0> (a java.lang.Object)

"container-0" #18 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104d0d4800 nid=0x101c2 waiting on condition [0x00007f0fd8918000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:570)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer$1.run(TomcatWebServer.java:179)

"Catalina-utility-2" #17 prio=1 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0fb4874000 nid=0x101c1 waiting on condition [0x00007f0fd8a19000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000003d4f64d00> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Catalina-utility-1" #16 prio=1 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104d0c7800 nid=0x101c0 waiting on condition [0x00007f0feebf0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000003d4f64d00> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"logback-1" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104cad9000 nid=0x1019c waiting on condition [0x00007f0fee6d8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000003d4a71430> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c25f000 nid=0x10166 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c253800 nid=0x10165 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c251800 nid=0x10164 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c24f800 nid=0x10163 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c24c800 nid=0x10162 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c24b000 nid=0x10161 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c21a000 nid=0x10160 in Object.wait() [0x00007f0fef3f8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    - locked <0x00000003d4279a90> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c215800 nid=0x1015f in Object.wait() [0x00007f0fef4f9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000003d4279c48> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c20b800 nid=0x1015e runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c01f000 nid=0x10154 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c020800 nid=0x10155 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c022800 nid=0x10156 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c024000 nid=0x10157 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c026000 nid=0x10158 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c028000 nid=0x10159 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c029800 nid=0x1015a runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c02b800 nid=0x1015b runnable 

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c02d800 nid=0x1015c runnable 

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c02f000 nid=0x1015d runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f104c261800 nid=0x10167 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1522
```

If I use **ps -ef|grep datax**, I can only see one process 65874.
But with the command **ps -elf | grep65874 | grep-v "grep"**, I can see hundreds of the same subprocesses.

```
root      65874      1  65874  0  162 May21 ?        00:00:00 java -jar data-collect-service-datax-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
root      65874      1  65875  0  162 May21 ?        00:00:08 java -jar data-collect-service-datax-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
root      65874      1  65876  0  162 May21 ?        00:00:08 java -jar data-collect-service-datax-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
root      65874      1  65877  0  162 May21 ?        00:00:08 java -jar data-collect-service-datax-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: did you try to read the `stderr` too?

Comment: oooh, I really didn't read **stderr**. Do I have to open a new thread to read **stderr**? Or call **process.destory**?

Comment: Can I close error stream instead of reading it, like `process.getErrorStream().close()`.